# Which Security Roles needs to be assigned to user to access the power apps in environment?

Tags: powerapps, security-roles, powerapps-modeldriven

I have developed an app in Power Apps environment solution. This app uses Dataverse tables from the environment.
There is no security group added to environment.
I have a solution created in this environment and have added the Dataverse tables in it. I have created app in the solution which uses the Dataverse table.
Now, I want to share this app with user from tenants which has license.
What are the basic Security Roles of the environment that needs to be assigned to the users who can then view both app and the Dataverse table.

I tried to give access to Basic User and min. Privilege security role user which did not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no minimum permission exclusively for the App, as long as user is able to login to Dynamics successfully with a role assigned & the role has access to the APP, user should be able to go into the app without any issue.

Roles for the app can be modified in the make.powerapps.com -> Apps-> Choose your app -> Share and select the security roles that should have access.

What the user can see inside the app entirely depends on access to the tables used in the App. Provide access to the tables via security roles as required and users should be able to access menus without any issue.

**Reference**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/model-driven-apps/share-model-driven-app#assign-security-roles-or-people-to-a-model-driven-app